# NetSuite Percent Complete Indicator

Tags: search, project, netsuite

My clients want me to show them the percentage of completion of a project.

I know that I can add the percentage complete to a saved search as shown in the search guide, but I have to show the percentage complete indicator.

Percent complete indicator in saved search:

[image: percent complete indicator in saved search]

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Formula (Text) result field to output your own HTML.

Example - `'<progress value="' || {fieldname} || '" max="100">'`

You can even get fancy and add CSS styling if you wanted

```
'<style>progress { height: 15px; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; } progress:after { content: attr(value)"%"; } </style><progress value="' || {fieldname} || '" max="100">'
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. I can user formula(text) to display progress bar now. We can add html and css to make it happen. Thanks again.